# XeTeXpicfile in vertical mode

Tags: graphics, xetex, tex-core, plain-tex

Given a minimal like

```
\line{%
  \vtop{\hsize=.6\hsize
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tempor lectus sit amet laoreet convallis. Quisque at est lacinia, porttitor justo quis, congue tortor. Pellentesque ac augue vitae felis facilisis convallis vel quis leo. Cras sapien quam, porttitor et molestie id, accumsan quis diam.

Ut id venenatis ante, in tincidunt leo. Praesent hendrerit, tellus vitae tristique blandit, tellus urna imperdiet dolor, ut mollis enim lacus id felis. Suspendisse ullamcorper sollicitudin diam, nec luctus velit dapibus eu.
  }\hfill%
  \vtop{\hsize=.4\hsize
    \XeTeXpicfile "kitten.jpg" width \hsize

    Foo
  }%
}

\bye
```

Where `kitten.jpg` is, for example, something from [placekitten](http://placekitten.com/200/300).

Where does the text `Foo` go? More importantly, why?

Also, why is there some mystery space above the image?

[image]

I would like to have a CSS `float: right` -like behavior.

Comment: This looks like a bug to me, I'll raise on xetex list.

Comment: http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2013-December/025032.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually my first answer was a little unfair. The behaviour of the xetex whatsit in vertical mode is very strange. Put it in hmode and it is far more reasonable.

[image]

```
\tracingall

\line{%
  \vtop{\hsize=.6\hsize
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tempor lectus sit amet laoreet convallis. Quisque at est lacinia, porttitor justo quis, congue tortor. Pellentesque ac augue vitae felis facilisis convallis vel quis leo. Cras sapien quam, porttitor et molestie id, accumsan quis diam.

Ut id venenatis ante, in tincidunt leo. Praesent hendrerit, tellus vitae tristique blandit, tellus urna imperdiet dolor, ut mollis enim lacus id felis. Suspendisse ullamcorper sollicitudin diam, nec luctus velit dapibus eu.
  }\hfill%
  \vtop{\hsize=.4\hsize
    \null
    \hbox{\XeTeXpicfile "kitten.jpg" width \hsize}%



    FooooooooooooooooooooooooX
  }%
}

\bye
```

The space at the top in your original is because the reference point is at the top of the image, so it aligns with the reference point which is the *baseline* of first row the text not its top. In hmode the reference point is at the bottom, but I put a `\null` their so that the vtop almost lined up, you would need to adjust by `\ht\strutbox` probably to get the reference point so the top of the image was with the top of the letters.

---

It looks like it is best to only ever use `\XeTeXpicfile` as the only thing in its list.
In the example below the X2 case has the correct external dimensions so `X` and `Y` are positioned as for a rule of the same with (X1) however `bbb` is bizarrely positioned. The box logging gives no indication but it is offset by its own width and overprints `Y`. If you put the picture whatsit in an `\hbox` as in X3, then the external dimensions are unchanged but `bbb` flips back inside the box and is positioned as in `X1`.

[image]

```
\tracingoutput1
\tracingonline1
\showboxbreadth\maxdimen
\showboxdepth\maxdimen

X1\hbox{\hbox{aaa}\vrule width 2cm\hbox{bbb}}Y

\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

X2\hbox{\hbox{aaa}\XeTeXpicfile "kitten.jpg" width 2cm\hbox{bbb}}Y

\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

X3\hbox{\hbox{aaa}\hbox{\XeTeXpicfile "kitten.jpg" width 2cm}\hbox{bbb}}Y

\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

X4\vbox{\hbox{aaa}\XeTeXpicfile "kitten.jpg" width 2cm\hbox{bbb}}Y

\bye
```

Comment: No duck? Oh no. `:)`

Comment: @Paulo: placeduck.com isn't taken ;)

Comment: @morbusg: ooh! `:)`